# Smart-contract and mint

Tags: erc-721, nft, mint

I would like to create a minting website for NFT. I have a question about implementation.

How the IPFS link can be retrieve in order to set the URI parameter? Do you I have to implement a database with all the links and call it when the minting button is pressed to get the IPFS link?

Answer (score 2):

Probably the most secure way is to have the links already in the minting contract (which is possibly the same as the NFT contract) and the contract then chooses the right link for the to-be-minted NFT.

If you input the link as a parameter to the minter, it means that a user can mint an NFT with any arbitrary link, just by calling the contract directly. This is probably not desirable.

Comment: This seems a good idea. Do you have an example?